# HTML5 validation on CENTOS Lamp server

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, centos

I have a form:

```
<form method"post" action="#" class="form-horizontal" id="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" id="email" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control" id="subject" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea name="message" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="send">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group hidden" id="successMsg">
    <label class="col-sm-2"></label>
    <label class="col-sm-10" style="color:#198C19;">Thanks for your message!</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Which I would like to have validated and have the cool little HTML5 popups next to it to denote that it is a required field, or that it is not an email address for the `type="email"` input element.  I had this working while on my local server on my machine.  But after moving it to my CentOS server it no longer works.   I am running LAMP on CentOS.  How might I get this to work?  I thought it was built into HTML5.  Also is it a possibility I have to do anything other than declare a doctype of `<!DOCTYPE html>` to ensure that it is treated as HTML5?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: ^Right, these bubble pops are not supported in < ie9.  It's also possible your browser is running in quirks mode, so you should use the DTD to force it into standards mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed that this code does work.
BTW: you mentioned your server; that really should not matter in the case of html; so long as the server sends the html, it's the browser that renders the markup (strictly client-side)

For sake of clarity, and just in case another tag is affecting the rendering, here is the complete example I tried on my local server (worked in IE11, FF28, chrome 33.0.1750.154 m and chrome canary)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<form method"post" action="#" class="form-horizontal" id="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" id="email" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control" id="subject" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea name="message" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="send">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group hidden" id="successMsg">
    <label class="col-sm-2"></label>
    <label class="col-sm-10" style="color:#198C19;">Thanks for your message!</label>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```